# How can I create a function that accepts user input integers into an array and exits the function if non-integer input is entered?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new to C++ in an intro class this semester, and I don't have a lot of prior coding experience. It feels like this shouldn't be that hard of an assignment, but it still has me stumped.

I created the function `fillArray()` that takes user input and enters it into an array called `numArray`. This function works great if I only enter numerical input, and if I don't try to exit the loop early, but I need it to exit properly when I try to do that.

I tried writing the `if`/`else` statement in `fillArray()` to break out of the loop if non-numerical input was entered,  but that didn't have the desired effect.

The assignment details are in the commented out text above my program. I haven't even gotten to the `reverseArray()` part of the problem yet, as I'm taking it one problem at a time.

```
// arrays.cpp

/* Write a program that uses the following functions:
Fill_array() takes as arguments the name of an array of int values and an array size. It prompts the
user to enter int values to be entered in the array. It ceases taking input when the array is full or when
the user enters non-numeric input, and it returns the actual number of entries.
Show_array() takes as arguments the name of an array of int values and an array size and displays
the contents of the array.
Reverse_array() takes as arguments the name of an array of int values and an array size and reverses
the order of the values stored in the array.
The program should use these functions to do the following:
fill an array, display the array, reverse the array, display the array, reverse all but the first and last
elements of the array, and finally, display the array.
Name your program arrays.cpp */

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fillArray(int array[], int size)
{
    int inputNum;

    for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        cout << "Enter an integer: ";
        cin >> inputNum;

        if((inputNum > -1000) && (inputNum < 1000))
            array[index] = inputNum;
        else
            break;   
    }
}

void showArray(int array[], int size)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        cout << array[index] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int numArray[10];

    fillArray(numArray, 10);
    showArray(numArray, 10);

    return 0;

}
```

I tried many different statements I found online in the `if`/`else` selection in `fillArray()`, and I cannot get the function to correctly exit the loop if non-numerical input is entered.

Comment: You're never testing whether `cin` is in a good or failed state, which can be as simple as `if (cin)` after attempting the extraction.

Comment: and on top of what Ben said u could loop there until u get a good input from the user or just exit as u wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple, but few are taught it for some reason: check the return value of `cin >> inputNum`.

```
        cout << "Enter an integer: ";
        if (cin >> inputNum)
            array[index] = inputNum;
        else
            break;
```

Technically, the result of `cin >> inputNum` is `cin` itself, which is why you can chain it togeather, but if the user enters anything that isn't a number, then the stream will set it's `fail` bit.  Then, when you call `if (cin)`, that checks if the stream has any error bits set.  So this can be used to check if all prior operations succeeded.

---

Unrelated, your function should `return false` or throw an exception to let the caller know that it failed to do its job.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the explaination. That helped me understand why it was wrong. With some tweaking I was able to come up with a way for it to return the number of entries made as well. Thank you.