# C++ array problem with default int values

Tags: c++

How to fix the problem with the default int values in the array?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main() {
    int arr[5];
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    


    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int input;
        cout << "Enter num # " << i + 1<<": ";
        cin >> input;
        if (input<-100 || input>100)
        {
            cerr << "Invalid number!";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i] = input;
        }
        
    }


    int smallest = arr[0];

    for (int number : arr)
    {
        if (number<smallest)
        {
            smallest = number;
        }
    }

    cout << "The smallest number is: " << smallest;


}
```

Is the default int value = 634906509 or sth like that?

Comment: Your compiler initialized stack memory to `0xcc` in debug mode to help you detect uninitialized memory when you debug your code: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/what-are-the-debug-memory-fill-patterns-in-visual-studio-c-and-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/what-are-the-debug-memory-fill-patterns-in-visual-studio-c-and-windows)

Comment: The problem in your code is once the user types a bad value instead of asking again you exit the loop then go on to use the whole array assuming you properly initialized all values.

Comment: The default value of an automatically allocated `int` is undefined. Typically you get whatever garbage happened to be left in memory by the last variable to use that memory, so you can be easily fooled if that last value was something friendly.

Answer (score 3):

> Thanks in advance! Default int value = 634906509 sth like that

The default values in the array are undefined (could be anything). Some systems will help you in debug mode by using a standard pattern for un-initialized memory. But you can't rely on that, and in production it's unlikely to happen.

To default initialize the array you can do:

```
int arr[5] = {0}; // Sets all values to zero.
```

If you want to initialize all values with something else you need to be specific.

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Side Note: This is C and not good practice in C++.

```
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
// The problem is that arrays turn into pointers very easily
// if you modify the code and this will still compile but
// give you the completely wrong answer.
```

Try:

```
std::size_t size = std::size(arr);
```

Comment: How to fix the problem?

Comment: @НикойНикоев `How to fix the problem with the default int values in the array?` I think I have shown how to set the default values?

Comment: What if the default value I entered is the smallest number...? I want to compare only the nums from the console and if the user types an invalid number the program should not print anything.

Comment: @НикойНикоев then you need to keep track of how many valid numbers the user input, and only analyze those

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77274664/how-can-i-create-a-function-that-accepts-user-input-integers-into-an-array-and-e/77274691?noredirect=1#comment136231263_77274691

Comment: @НикойНикоев If the user enters an invalid number then don't do the second loop. You will need to have a variable to inidcate if all the values are good. If they enter a bad value record that you have bad input. Then check this variable before doing the second loop.

Comment: My question is what do you actually want to happen when a bad value is entered? Do you want to keep prompting until `size` values are entered? Or do you want to  loop over just the valid values possibly exiting the program if the user entered 'a' or some other invalid input for the first input. If you want to loop over just the valid values you will want to change the range based for loop to a regular for loop and reduce `size` to the number of valid values.

Comment: When the user enters an invalid number I want the program to print out "Invalid number!" and then to stop.

Comment: You could replace `break;` with `return 1;` or `return EXIT_FAILURE;` and add `#include <cstdlib>` to the top of your source file. The program will then end after printing "Invalid number!" because returning from main() ends your program.